# How to create an hyperlink to switch from one report to another in PowerBI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi

I have got 4 PowerBI reports. Do you know if there is possible to swicht from one report to the other 3 reports with for example an hyperlink?
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-dashboards)?

If you actually want a hyperlink instead, on the ribbon click Insert -> Textbox. Paste the url of your report in there and ensure you click the hyperlink button to turn it into a link.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My reports are saved on my directory. And I would like to change reports within the same directores. The directory address for example is: X:\XXX\Daten\Dashboards\Auswertungen with such kind of directory links it does not work.

Comment: Reports are supposed to be uploaded to the Power BI service. Local file system is only supported for the creation of the reports and not the consumption.